# Inequality $a^2+4b^2<1$.

Tags: inequality, geometric-inequalities

Let $a,b$ be two strictly positive real numbers that satisfy $a^3+b^3=a-b$. How can I prove that $a^2+4b^2<1$?

So because $a^3+b^3$ is $>0$ I know that $a>b$.

I tried using $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$ but that didn‘t lead me anywhere...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$\frac {a^3+b^3 } { a-b}=1 $$

We show that $$a^2 +4b^2 <\frac {a^3+b^3 } { a-b}$$

Since $a-b$ is positive we  may multiply both sides by $a-b$ to get $$(a^2+4b^2)(a-b)< a^3+b^3$$
After simplification on both sides we get $$a^2-4ab+5b^2>0$$
That is the same as $$(a-2b)^2+b^2 >0$$ which is true.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a less clever (but always working) method:
Lets maximize $F(x,y)=x^2+4y^2$ under the constrains $x,y\ge 0$ and $x^3+y^3-x+y=0$ using [Lagrange multipliers.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) Let $f(x,y,\lambda)=F(x,y)+\lambda(x^3+y^3-x+y),$ then $$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2x+3\lambda x^2-\lambda,\,\,\,\,\,\,\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}=8x+3\lambda y^2+\lambda ,\,\,\,\,\,\,\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial\lambda}=x^3+y^3-x+y$$ and we get a highly non-linear system of equations. With the help of [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+2x%2B6x%5E2z-z%3D0%2C+8y%2B3y%5E2z%2Bz%3D0%2C+x%5E3%2By%5E3-x%2By%3D0) we can have very accurate approximate solutions (Exact solutions are bit complicated). Now for $$x\approx 0.9725956862081514773 ,\,\,\,\,\,\, y\approx 0.0524320766715842$$ we get $$F(x,y)\approx 0.95693885948708459008$$ which is a very good approximation of the maximum of $F.$

Comment: Hi Bumblebee, I like your answer because it is very systematic (+1) but I have to accept the other answer because it is more clever

Comment: @StackUnderflow: Of course. I also like the simple way solve this.